# Resharper - blank lines between properties with attributes

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to make resharper add blank lines between single line properties only when they contain attributes?

[image]

With Roslyn 'references' info, I find the code above  a little too condensed, and I'd rather have it like below:

[image]

However, for single line properties it's all fine when there are no additional spaces (especially that references info adds some whitespace anyway)

[image]

I've seen the options to configure whitespaces, but they don't seem to handle 'has attributes' condition.